Unknown stimulus opens unknown popup menu
I am running Ubuntu 24.04.1. I haven't figured out how to attach or insert the picture produced by "Print Screen", so I reproduce the popup window mentioned in the title with text characters.
 -----------------------------
| Take Screenshot             |
| Hide                        |
| Restore                     | 
| Move                        |
| Resize                      |
| Always on Top               |
| Always on Visible Workspace |
| Move to Workspace Right     |
|-----------------------------|
| Close                       |
 -----------------------------

To the best of my knowledge, this window only appears when I am entering characters from a chat box or a text window subordinate to my browser, Firefox 130.0.1. I don't know if the popup is generated by Ubuntu or Firefox. Does anyone recognize this as an Ubuntu popup?
The scenario is this: I am typing away, entering text and for some reason the cursor moves out of the text/chat box. I don't know what I do to cause this to happen. I keep entering text and evidently hit some button that causes the popup to appear. Does anyone know what causes this popup to be displayed?
Thanks,
John

does this Firefox Support Page hold any clues?

It thinks you Right-Clicked on the top bar of your screen, and it's offering window configuration options. Click your mouse somewhere else, and it should vsnish.
